# Detecting programmatically whether axis labels overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to detect whether axis labels overlap in `ggplot2` programmatically?

Suppose I create the following graph:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

dt <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("name") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(cyl == 8)

ggplot(dt, aes(x = name, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

I want to programmatically detect whether x-axis labels are overlapping and apply the following first remedy:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = name, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

[image]

Here is the tricky part. Say the dimensions are different and first remedy also overlaps like this:

[image]

I want to apply a second remedy like this:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = name, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
```

[image]

Is it possible without visually inspecting the graph?

Comment: Yes, but it's complicated. Whether the labels overlap is not just dependent on the plotting code - it also depends on the dimensions of the plotting device. So any code will need to check the dimensions of the plotting device, and the plot the code produces will be incorrect if you (or your users) resize the plotting device.

Comment: I understand the requirement, but this could be solved by `coord_flip`: longer labels on Y axis.

Comment: @AllanCameron, I agree with the difficulty especially if the plot dimensions can change (as I did between second and third plots). Still, supposing that we have a fixed size predefined output dimension, is it possible to detect overlapping axis labels? For example, `geom_text_repel()` does it AFIK for labels.

@zx8754 Yes, for these graphs, `coord_flip` might be a better choice. But my more general question about detecting overlapping axis labels still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Not a definitive solution, but if we consider the margins constant, we can do some simple subtraction:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

dt <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("name") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(cyl == 8)

p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = name, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()


# variable part
font_size <- 9 #points, the ggplot default
full_width <- 15 #cm
full_height <- 10 #cm

cm_to_pt <- 28.35 # 1 cm = 28.35 points

# try varying width
for(full_width in c(30, 40, 45, 50)){
  axis_text_length_pt <- ceiling(max(nchar(dt$name))/2)*font_size
  axis_available_pt <- full_width/n_distinct(dt$name)*cm_to_pt
  do_not_touch <- axis_text_length_pt <= axis_available_pt
  
  p +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=font_size)) +
    geom_text(aes(x=5,y=15, label=do_not_touch))
  ggsave(paste0("tmp_",full_width,".png"),
         width = full_width, height = full_height, unit = "cm")
}
```

At 40 cm we still have the Hornet Sportabout and the Lincoln Continental touching, at 45 cm they separate.